recuadro en cursos de visual studio code
en visual studio code me aparece un recuadro en el cursor, no sé cómo se activó, antes no me aparecía eso. ¿Alguien podría decirme cómo quitar ese recuadro y solo aparezca mi cursor, por favor?

